# C# Namespace Guidelines

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

I'm trying to follow Microsoft guidelines for namespace names (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026(v=vs.110).aspx) but I suck at picking names that match the guidelines. Can you suggest examples of a namespace for email services?

Comment: Ummm, what does "I suck at it" mean? Why cant you do `MyCompany.MyLibrary` or `MyCompany.MyLibrary.Email`?

Comment: The guidelines specify the following:

**<Company>.(<Product>|<Technology>)[.<Feature>][.<Subnamespace>]**

For an email service I would think **MyCompany.Services.Email** would work but "Services" isn't really a product or technology IMO. I'm partitioning an app that could be around for 10 or 15 years so I'd like to get this right.

Comment: All a namespace is for is to separate types so you don't have name collisions.  It adds zero value in terms of functionality or usability, so there's no "wrong" answer so long as it doesn't collide with an existing namespace.  Services is a perfectly choice for "technology" if you don't have an overarching name for the email service at your company.

Answer (score 3):

If `MyCompany.Services.Email` doesn't suit you, you can name your service information system and use that in the namespace instead of "Services". For example: "MyCompany Information System" => MCIS. The namespace is now:
`MyCompany.MCIS.Email`.

Now you can treat MCIS like a Product/Technology, just like the guidelines specify. This is a common approach.